# Redirecting a Subdomain to URL with query, using PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, user-profile

I am trying to create a way to issue the website members their own profile pages with a subdomain as their URL (user.domain.com), but I want those subdomains to just redirect to the domain with query string, like this: domain.com?UserId=3

I need those subdomains to only be aliases and not really exist. How would I achieve this using PHP on the fly, while creating their profile account?

Thanks so much.

Comment: All subdomains are mostly aliases, since they hardly refer to an actual computer. Nowadays everything is an alias

Answer (score 1):

You need to wildcard your DNS records first.

See for more information about wildcarding on:
http://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/lets-get-started/dns-name-servers/wildcard-dns-what-is-it-and-how-do-i-use-it

http://codex.wordpress.org/Configuring_Wildcard_Subdomains

http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/dns/ch16_02.htm

Then you need to get a username based on domain. You can use parse_url and then split string to get the username (http://php.net/parse_url).

Comment: Stackoverflow requires not only referencing pages but also explaining its content

Comment: Ok that makes sense... Wildcard DNS record directs back to the main domain, then I just parse the URL and pull the username from the subdomain and proceed. This is what I needed to know. Thank you Adil.

Comment: @user3281692, you are absolutely right. If you have difficulties I can provide the php code.